# Is this docker-for-mac password dialog legit?

Tags: macos, security, docker

I know docker is a hodgepodge or tools and hacks, but recently after an update docker asks me for my password in the most odd way:

First it show me this dialog
[image: Dialog warning docker will ask me for the password]

Then it show this regular-application-dialog instead of the safe, os specific one (which would also allow me to log in with other means, such as touchbar)
[image: Docker amateur password dialog]

Look how bizarre this dialog is. It shows my Full name pre-filled in the username field. Then the, what i assume is the OK button, has no label, is a different blue than normal default buttons, and is out of alignment with other form elements.

Their "extensive documentation" (quote from their github) only mentions, in passing and without screenshots:

> You are prompted to authorize Docker.app with your system password after you launch it. Privileged access is needed to install networking components and links to the Docker apps.
>   (from https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/ )

A search for "password dialog" on their github issues only show (recurring) issues about the dialog being shown over and over. No concerns about any of the above.

Is this legit? Or am I about to fall for something?

Comment: Docker is a rather clean and elegant system on its native platform :)

Comment: @xenoid very few Op Tools survive a look under the hood :D but docker has a little more hacks than most. dockerd still run as root on any platforms and the network hacks are necessary on them all. for-mac just makes things a little worse with this dialog and default ssh-private keys all around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue today as I was updating, and it unnerved me. Digging into it more, it seems likely to be an OS-level issue.

[This GitHub Issues comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/39648#issuecomment-518192195) explains the issue from the point of view of a contributor at Docker. Also, a comment further down the thread points to [evidence on an Apple Developer Forums thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/44873) indicating that the issue might be quite a bit older.

These links helped set my mind at ease, and I continued with the installation. Hopefully it's helpful to someone in the future as well.

Comment: Nice finding, I also had doubts in entering the password, and this post helper me decide :)